# ruby OCI8 slow initialization

Tags: ruby, oracle, oracle11g, oci8

I'm developing API for product based on Oracle database and I tried to use ruby-oci8 gem, but I faced a strange problem - OCI8.new is very slow, it takes 1,2-1,5 second to connect to database.

**For example:**

```
~ mmulev$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > require 'oci8'
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > def test
2.1.1 :003?>   t0 = Time.now
2.1.1 :004?>   OCI8.new('SCHEMA', 'STRONG_PASS', '//db_host:port/service_name')
2.1.1 :005?>   Time.now - t0
2.1.1 :006?>   end
 => :test 
2.1.1 :007 > test
 => 1.217809 
2.1.1 :008 >
```

The same thing in php (oci_new_connect) needs approximately 0,1-0,2 second to establish connection and return handler.

Is there any other solutions besides connection pooling?

P.S. ruby API code was profiled by method_profiler and by Benchmark, oracle v - 11g

Comment: Are you using the exact same connection string for PHP? Do you have multiple `ORACLE_HOME`s on your client?

Comment: Sure, use a [n-tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) design and connect from ruby (or php) to your middle-tier. Of course, your middle-tier will probably need a connection pool to connect to your database with decent performance.

Comment: @frank-schmitt, connection string is the same and ORACLE_HOME is only one

Comment: Use the force. Use strace, and you will see where it hangs.

Comment: FWIW, this is not reproducible. Connecting to a local XE instance in a Docker container with `OCI8.new('user', 'pass', '//localhost:1521/xe')` took 0.015 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this gem to connect to oracle

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced

Make sure that you have installed oracle properly you can install this by following link : [How to install ruby-oci8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894194/how-to-install-ruby-oci8)

Comment: How does this answer the question? That gem seems to be an ActiveRecord wrapper around ruby-oci8 - how could using that be faster than plain ruby-oci8?

Comment: using the oracle-enhanced gem you can easily configure your rails app  and query the database . If database read/write becomes slow then you may have to index some fields or  some other issues with database :)

Comment: Sorry, but this is totally irrelevant to the question. The OP didn't mention Rails at all (*Ruby != Rails*), and creating indices will certainly *not* speedup logging on to the database.

Comment: ? The question doesn't contain the words *Rails* or *REST*, so IMHO this answer is still irrelevant. But YMMV, of course.